# Phonegap Build: the app was not installed on the iPhone because it requires a newer version of iPhone software

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I've been using Phonegap Build for developing hybrid apps for some time. But after August 3rd, the QA reported one app we're currently developing stopped working on iPohne 4S running iOS 7.1.2. Whenever they try to install or upgrade the app using iTunes they get the message on the title.

I've downgraded the cli version to the one previously working fine using `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.2.0" />` and specified directly to support iOS 7 by adding the deployment target using `<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />`, in both cases the app compiles successfully, but it doesn't install on the iPhone.

The UDID of the phone is also included on the provisioning profile so that shouldn't be part of the problem, and the Developer certificates and the account are up to date and working. I've also checked the supported platforms of the cli here: https://build.phonegap.com/current-support and as I understand it should support iOS 7 natively.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching the Phonegap Build team on their community forum and twitter, looks like it's an unsolved bug with `cli 6.0.0` at least and newer. After making a rollback to `cli 5.2.0` the app started working as expected. If anyone experiences a similar issue in the future with this or any other recent implemented cli version, that should do the trick.